# Azure DevOps Build Solution using wrong version of package

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I've got a 'Build Solution' step for a ASP.NET project in Azure DevOps and it's failing because it's trying to use an old version of a package. In my code it's only referenced in the packages.config and I've changed that entry to use version 1.0.7, but in Azure DevOps it's still trying to find 1.0.2 but fails to find it. Any ideas why it's trying to use the wrong package version or how to force it to get the new one? My project in visual studio has no references to the old version.

Comment: Probably any of your nuget package requres version 1.0.2 of that package?

Comment: Ahh yes, after removing the old version of the package from my packages folder locally I get the error when building in Visual Studio. Not sure how to find which other one thinks it needs version 1.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were references in the .csproj file that were trying to access the old file path, and that version of the package did not exist at that path. So I took the bad path out and it fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of your NuGet packages requires version 1.0.2 of the package. To figure out which one, delete the local version 1.0.2 and build the solution locally. Then take a look at the build output and see which package is missing that version. Maybe take a look here:
[Increase Build Log Verbosity to Get More Details About a Build Problem](https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/Blog/increase-build-log-verbosity-details-build-problem)